# Irreducibility of a polynomial in two variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Anyone knows how to verify that the polynomial 
$$(ax)^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1x+a_0-y^n$$ is irreducible, where $n\geq 2$,  $a,a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a\neq 0$, and $(ax)^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1x+a_0$ is not a $d$-th power in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ for any divisor  $d\geq 2$ of $n$.

Comment: Page 297, theorem 9.1 in Serge Lang's Algebra would help.

Comment: Excuse me, what edition are you talking about? in the third edition there is no theorem 9.1 in page 297.

Comment: The section entitled possibly "the equation X^n-a", revised 3ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the polynomial by $F$, then $F=-(y^n-b)$ where $b\in \mathbb{Q}(x)$.

Verify that the $b$ is satisified the conditions in Theorem 9.1, chapter VI, Part two, in Serge Lang's Algebra, GTM 211, 3rd ed.

Suppose the polynomial,  $F$, is not irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$[x,y], then $-F=GH$ for some non-units $G,H\in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. Comparing the coefficient of $y^n$, $G$ and $H$ must be non-constant in $y$, i.e., $G,H$ are of degree $\geq 1$ with respcet to $y$. Thus we have a non-trivial factorizaiton of $-F=y^n-b\in \mathbb{Q}(x)[y]$.  So by Theorem 9.1, in chapter VI, Part two in Serge Lang's Algebra, GTM 211, 3rd ed, we obtain a contradiction.